# Configure Webmatrix for Windows Users

Tags: web-config, webmatrix

I create asp .net page and i have use windows user to authenticate.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

I create simply page with one label and display information.

```
if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        Label1.Text = "Authenticated = 'TRUE'<br/>";
        Label1.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name;
}
else
{
        Label1.Text = "Authenticated = 'FALSE'<br/>";
}
```

I often get **Authenticated = 'FALSE'**

How configure web.config and WebMatrix to take user from Windows?

Comment: In general, I would think that would work, but curious where you're running this.  Locally on IIS Express or ???  Might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you published your web site without changing authentication on the corresponding virtual directory of IIS.

You should deactivate "Anonymous" authentication and activate "Windows" authentication. The existence of `<authentication mode="Windows" />` line in `web.config` is not enough for IIS. Moreover "Windows" authentication must be installed of cause (see for example [this](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication) for more information).

Comment: does that mean you can't have Windows Authentication running IIS Express on Windows 7?

Comment: btw, I think when you say "of cause" you mean "of course"  :)

Comment: @Knox: Yes "of course". The question contains no information about the web server used. I suppose that it is more likely standard IIS. What I mean in my answer that if both "Anonymous" and "Windows" authentications are enabled, the connected users will be not authenticated. So practically only "Anonymous" authentication will be used. To be able to use "Windows" authentication one have to disable "Anonymous" authentication, which is enabled per default.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```